# How to set a counter for duplicate values in React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

My code is basically a form with a text input and a submit button. Each time the user input data, my code adds it to an array and shows it under the form.

It is working fine; however, when I add duplicate values, it still adds it to the list. I want my code to count these duplicates and show them next to each input.
For example, if I input two "Hello" and one "Hi" I want my result to be like this:
2 Hello
1 Hi

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import ShoppingItem from './ShoppingItem';




class ShoppingList extends React.Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props);

        this.state ={
           shoppingCart: [],
            newItem :'',
            counter: 0        };

    }

    handleChange =(e) => 
    {
        this.setState ({newItem: e.target.value });
    }

    
    handleSubmit = (e) =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        let newList;
        let myItem ={
            name: this.state.newItem,
            id:Date.now()
        }
        if(!this.state.shoppingCart.includes(myItem.name))
        {
            newList = this.state.shoppingCart.concat(myItem);
        }
        if (this.state.newItem !=='')
        {
            this.setState(
                {
                   shoppingCart: newList
                }
         );
        }
        this.state.newItem ="" ;
    }
```

the rest of my code is like this:

```
render(){      
        return(
            <div className = "App">

                <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
                    <h6>Add New Item</h6>
                    <input type = "text" value = {this.state.newItem} onChange ={this.handleChange}/>
                    <button type = "submit">Add to Shopping list</button>
                </form>
                <ul>
                        {this.state.shoppingCart.map(item =>(

                                
                                <ShoppingItem item={item} key={item.id} />
                        )                         
                          )}
                </ul>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ShoppingList;
```

Comment: Where is the `render` function?

Comment: you can use a map in state to store the string and count(as key value pair) and on handleChange just update the count of values in the map

Comment: Please share your `render` function.

Comment: I just added the rest of the code which contains map and render

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

1. `this.state.shoppingCart` is an array of objects, so `this.state.shoppingCart.includes(myItem.name)` will *always* return false as it won't find a value that is a string.
2. `this.state.newItem = "";` is a state mutation

## Solution

1. Check the `newItem` state first, if empty then return early
2. Search `this.state.shoppingCart` for the index of the first matching item by name property
3. If found then you want to map the cart to a new array and then also copy the item into a new object reference and update the quantity.
4. If not found then copy the array and append a new object to the end with an initial quantity 1 property.
5. Update the shopping cart and newItem state.

Code

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!this.state.newItem) return;

  let newList;

  const itemIndex = this.state.shoppingCart.findIndex(
    (item) => item.name === this.state.newItem
  );

  if (itemIndex !== -1) {
    newList = this.state.shoppingCart.map((item, index) =>
      index === itemIndex
        ? {
            ...item,
            quantity: item.quantity + 1
          }
        : item
    );
  } else {
    newList = [
      ...this.state.shoppingCart,
      {
        name: this.state.newItem,
        id: Date.now(),
        quantity: 1
      }
    ];
  }

  this.setState({
    shoppingCart: newList,
    newItem: ""
  });
};
```

***Note:** Remember to use `item.name` and `item.quantity` in your `ShoppingItem` component.*

[image: Edit how-to-set-a-counter-for-duplicate-values-in-react]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your "handleSubmit" with below one and check

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { shoppingCart, newItem } = this.state;
    const isInCart = shoppingCart.some(({ itemName }) => itemName === newItem);
    let updatedCart = [];
    let numberOfSameItem = 1;
    if (!isInCart && newItem) {
      updatedCart = [
        ...shoppingCart,
        {
          name: `${numberOfSameItem} ${newItem}`,
          id: Date.now(),
          itemName: newItem,
          counter: numberOfSameItem
        }
      ];
    } else if (isInCart && newItem) {
      updatedCart = shoppingCart.map((item) => {
        const { itemName, counter } = item;
        if (itemName === newItem) {
          numberOfSameItem = counter + 1;
          return {
            ...item,
            name: `${numberOfSameItem} ${itemName}`,
            itemName,
            counter: numberOfSameItem
          };
        }
        return item;
      });
    }
    this.setState({
      shoppingCart: updatedCart,
      newItem: ""
    });
  };
```

Comment: @Moona, edited a little. You don't need counter in state but you need one in every object to keep track how many same item ordered.